# Match all files (folders and subfolders) expect the files in specific folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been searching and trying to figure out this problem for weeks, but no result :( I am not good at regex.

I need a .htaccess regex match, that will match all files, folders, and Rewrite them in htaccess to /mimox.com/ folder

so the files and folders I got on the server are:

```
http://limiagrade.com/mimox.com/index.php
http://limiagrade.com/mimox.com/css/style.css
http://limiagrade.com/mimox.com/img/bg.jpg
http://limiagrade.com/mimox.com/img/header.jpg
http://limiagrade.com/mimox.com/faq.php
http://limiagrade.com/mimox.com/
```

I want to make my htaccess to access my files without mimox.com in URL.

So when I access, for example:

```
http://limiagrade.com/faq.php
```

it should Rewrite using htaccess to:

```
http://limiagrade.com/mimox.com/faq.php
```

I tried many things, but they always go into infinite loop.. :/

Comment: You probably just need to add a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before the rule which means if the requested file doesn't exist, continue with the rule.

Comment: Or a condition that checks if the requested file doesn't have `mimox.com` in the path.

Comment: could you please write me the code for rewriting all files expect those ones which contain mimox.com/

Comment: Found a solution:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} limiagrade\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!.*(mimox.com)).*)$ mimox.com/$1

Comment: Wow O_o Not being good at regex and using a negative lookforward in the solution within 15 minutes of posting the question? O_o

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^mimox.com /mimox.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```